# informing an editor

Tags: discussion, edits

There is an editor currently working their way through the tkinter tag, who is in some cases completely rewriting content (which is grammatically correct) to conform with their personal style. They are also changing code in a similar way.

I'm not opposed to people editing my answers; however, I have in most cases put significant thought into my writing, and obviously prefer my style.

How am I supposed to inform this person?

[Editing guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: `adding additional content` The editing guidelines *explicitly* state that this should **not** be done.

Comment: You leave a comment on your post with `@<the editors username>` and the editor would be notified.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. Can you provide a link for these guidelines? I mostly agree with this stance, especially when editors include information already stated in another answer.

Comment: @HonestAbe Right in the help center: "When should I edit posts? [...] To clarify the meaning of the post **(without changing that meaning)**"  (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Servy You can add content without changing the meaning of the answer; so I don't really agree that it is explicitly stated that adding additional content should not be done. In fact it also states that: "to add related resources or hyperlinks" is OK, which is adding additional content. Here is the link for anyone interested http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're suggested edits, rather than actual edits, reject the suggestions.

Edits purely changing content from something valid to something equally valid, but of a different style based on their personal preference (whether this be code or not) is inappropriate.  Content should remain in the original author's voice (at least if at all possible).

If the edits are actual edits (or a lot of them start getting approved by others), flag for moderator attention.  You can optionally comment if you want (you can @ reply to an editor) to explain that what they're doing isn't appropriate.  You can revert the edits once, but you shouldn't get into an edit war if the user starts rolling back your edits; if that happens only a mod can resolve the situation.